# How to call function of object passed by interop?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, interop, com-interop

I have the following code pattern:

```
[VB6] 
Dim objNetDllObject As New NetDllObject 
objNetDllObject.PassVb6Form(MyForm) 
objNetDllObject.ShowForm  

[C#] 
object Vb6Form;  
private void PassVb6Form(object form) { Vb6Form = form; } 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Vb6Form.Show(); }
```

The problem is that the C# compiler does not like the `Vb6Form.Show()` statement, because `Show()` is not a function of `object`, which is true.  How can I compile this code?

Comment: Type casts? The problem is VB is loathe bound as such the type is determined at runtime and if the function doesn't exist then, the program crashes. Pretty stupid if you ask me

Comment: Can you use dynamic in place of object? `dynamic Vb6Form`

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I don't think I will have a problem with the function not existing at run-time. My problem is that it won't even compile.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: how do I typecast to a VB6 object when in C#?

Comment: @BobHorn: I am using C# 2.0 so `dynamic` or `var` is not available.

Comment: Oh whoops my mistake. You need reflection to do this.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: ok, any hints about what function to call?  Is it something like `TypeOf` ?

Comment: Yes. But I can't help you ATM. My parents took my computer away and it has all of my code on it

Comment: You could try adding a reference to the appropriate VB runtime DLL and then it can be strongly type.

Comment: @Deanna: what would be the DLL if the object is a VB6 Form?

Comment: I expect `msvbvm60.dll` but I wouldn't know without checking. Mine are showing in the `VB6.olb` installed with VB6.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve the problem like this (since VB6 has a reference to NetDllObject, I am guessing it has a reference and can implement other objects as well)

Expose an interface in .Net that you would like your VB6 interface to implement:

```
public interface IVB6Form
{
     void Show();
}
```

Implement this in VB6 in a new class:

```
Implements IVB6Form

Public myForm as Form

Public Sub IVB6Form_Show()
    myForm.Show()  
End Form
```

Change the C# signature to use that instead of an object reference:

```
private void PassVb6Form(IVB6Form form) { Vb6Form = form; }
```